# how to transfer data from one view to another in net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to create another model transferring some data from previous view. Actually I need to transfer key to save relation between objects. What are the best practices?

In my case I have one view representing a model of car and I need to start a next view representing a part containing the foreign key to the car. How to do this?

I need to transfer some attributes from one model/view to another model/view while creating. I mean passing foreign key need to keep relation in a different view(model). I tried to use the form but the web page dosen't appear to fill in the other attributes.

```
<form asp-action="CreateFromFirstView" asp-controller="secondControler" style="display:inline;">
        <input type="hidden" name="KeyID" value="@Model.KeyID" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-imary">CreateFromFirstView</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a ViewModel and send to other view the object like a Model.

Example

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
var vm = new VehicleDetailsViewController();
return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(VehicleDetailsViewController vm)
{
 //Validation something wrong
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(vm);

 //Make what you want with all OK
return View("AllOk");
}
```

Comment: I need to transfer some attributes from one model/view to another model/view while creating. I mean passing foreign key need to relation in a different view(model).

Comment: I need to transfer some attributes from one model/view to another model/view while creating. I mean passing foreign key need to relation in a different view(model). I tried to use the form but the web page dosen't appear to fill in the other attributes.

<form asp-action="CreateFromFirstView" asp-controller="secondControler" style="display:inline;">
        <input type="hidden" name="KeyID" value="@Model.keyID" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">CreateFromFirstView</button>
    </form>

Comment: If you transfer the same attributes, why no use the same viewModel object? can you copy all the code ? update the question with Controller, View, Jquery .... to help you better, with the form only i can't help you a lot